# Dúvida sobre injeção de dependência em event listener do hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, vraptor

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma maneira de eu injetar recursos em um Event Listener do hibernate usando vraptor 3.5.
Queria poder simular o comportamento de uma trigger que temos no banco de dados. E esse Listener faria um update no banco.

Eu tenho o seguinte objeto:

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(value=ContaEntradaListener.class)
@Table(name = "nfeide", schema = "coliseunfe")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "coliseunfe.gen_idnfeide", sequenceName = "coliseunfe.gen_idnfeide")
public class Nfeide implements java.io.Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = -4072081791666953260L;
private long idnfeide;
private Filial filial;
private Funcuser funcuser;
private long nnf;
private Long nnfnota;
private Long nnfnotahomo;
private int cnf;
private Tipopagamento tipopagamento;
private Modelo modelo;
private Serie serie;
private LocalDateTime demi;
private LocalDateTime dsaient;
private LocalTime hsaient;
private Integer tpnfe;
etc...
```

Como da pra ver ali eu tenho declarado um Event Listener, que segue abaixo:

```
public class ContaEntradaListener{

private ContaentradaRepository contaentradaRepository;

public ContaEntradaListener() {
    /*contaentradaRepository = new ContaentradaBusiness(null, null);*/
}

@PreUpdate  
public void preUpdate(Object object){

    Nfeide nfeide = (Nfeide) object;
    char statusnota = nfeide.getStatusnota();
    List<Nfecontaentrada> nfecontaentradas = new ArrayList<>(nfeide.getNfecontaentradas());

    for(Nfecontaentrada nfecontaentrada: nfecontaentradas){
        Contaentrada contaentrada = nfecontaentrada.getContaentrada();

        if(statusnota == 'a'){
            String descricao = "NRO. NOTA: " + nfeide.getNnf();
            contaentradaRepository.atualizaContaentradaStatus(contaentrada.getIdcontaentrada(), "p");
            contaentradaRepository.atualizaContaentradaDescricao(contaentrada.getIdcontaentrada(), descricao);

        } else if(statusnota == 'c'){
            contaentradaRepository.atualizaContaentradaStatus(contaentrada.getIdcontaentrada(), "n");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Sei que a pergunta pode ser meio besta, mas seria interessante eu achar uma solução para essa questão de transformar as triggers em java, pra ajudar na manutenção.
Desde há agradeço